# Socket message program not working with multiple devices

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I have made a program using the socket library that allows me to start a server to collect messages from a client that connects, and I have also created a client that can connect to the server and send messages.
These programs both communicate with each other when tested on the same device, but as soon as I try communicate between two different devices I get varied errors.
I mostly get errors saying that the connection was refused, or that it timed out, or that the IP does not apply in this context.
I have been searching for a solution all over but none are working, please help.

Server code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import socket

print("STARTING_SERVER_SETUP_AT: " + str(datetime.now()))

ip = raw_input("SERVER_IP: ")
port = int(raw_input("SERVER_PORT: "))

address = (ip, port)
max_size = 1000

print("STARTING_THE_SERVER_AT: " + str(datetime.now()))

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(5)
client, addr = server.accept()

while(True):
    data = client.recv(max_size)
    print(str(datetime.now()) + ": " + str(data))
    client.sendall(bytes("MESSAGE_RECEIVED"))
```

Client code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import socket

print("STARTING_CLIENT_SETUP_AT: " + str(datetime.now()))

ip = raw_input("SERVER_IP: ")
port = int(raw_input("SERVER_PORT: "))
username = raw_input("CLIENT_USERNAME: ") + ": "

address = (ip, port)
max_size = 1000

print("STARTING_CLIENT_AT: " + str(datetime.now()))

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(address)

while(True):
    client.sendall(bytes(username + raw_input()))
```

For more info:
This is written in Python2.7
and I have tried EVERY SINGLE COMBINATION of IP's to get this
thing to work (0.0.0.0, 127.0.x.x, 192.168.x.x, localhost)
I also can't port forward.

Comment: Just another piece of info: I can't port forward.

Comment: If you need to add more information you should edit your question to include it.

Comment: You need to find out the ip address of your server. You won't need to input it when you start the server code. You *will* need this address for the client.

Comment: Ok, will do....

Comment: I have it already, it's the 192.168.x.x number, however the connecting client still quits due to the errors mentioned in the question.

Comment: You need to find out the ip address of your server machine. Your server code should be `ip = ''` instead of asking for input, and you can type the ip address of your server into your client.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Comment: I changed my program to your specs and it still works on my computer tested by itself, but it still doesn't work between two deviecs. The client doesn't connect and the error printed says: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond.

Comment: I tried your code on two machines, but with fixed ip address (that of the machine running the server code). The only problems I encountered was encoding since I was using Python 3.6, but it worked once that was fixed.

Comment: :/ Sounds like I need an upgrade... Any possible way to get it working on 2.7?

Comment: Fixed now, turns out my router was blocking direct communication between devices.